# Using Scrapy Python not able to extract data from response html with xpath due to namespace

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, namespaces, web-crawler

I am using scrapy with xpath to extract data from a webpage. My html response looks like this,

[image]

I want to extract the href link present in the highlighted **"a" tag**.

Usually I use **response.xpath('//a[@id="jr-alt-sw"]/@href')** to get the data, but here I think due to the namespace problem the result is empty. How can I get the data if namespace is present.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: What namespace issue are you referring to? We need a [mcve]. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: there is no `href` attribute for the highlighted `a` tag in here.

Answer (score 0):

Is that true about namespace? Another reason to use css instead:

```
response.css('a#jr-alt-sw::attr(href)')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `href` attribute available for the selected `a` tag here, Check out for the next `a` tag that contains the `href` attribute.

```
response.xpath('//a[@id="jr-pdf-sw"]/@href')
```